# How to namespace modules in the browser but not in node

Tags: node.js

I have seen many examples of the self-invoking pattern that detects the global object (module.export / window) -- but I am not sure how to do namespacing with this pattern and still have it work in node the same way.

```
(function(exports) {
    'use strict';

    // how do i do something like this and have it work in node as well
    // exports Namespace.Models.HelloWorld = function () {}

    exports.say = function() {
        return 'hello world';
    };
}(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this.helloworld = {} : exports));
```

Comment: Did one of my answers help you solve your question?

Comment: Not necessarily but I'm going to check it anyways. I realized I didnt need to reuse my code in both environments for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Write your modules in the node-style and then let browserify turn them into proper client-side scripts :)

### *From browserify home page:*

Write your browser code with node.js-style requires:

```
// main.js

var foo = require('./foo');
var gamma = require('gamma');

var n = gamma(foo(5) * 3);
var txt = document.createTextNode(n);
document.body.appendChild(txt);
```

Export functionality by assigning onto module.exports or exports:

```
// foo.js

module.exports = function (n) { return n * 11 }
```

Install modules with npm:

```
npm install gamma
```

Now recursively bundle up all the required modules starting at main.js into a single file with the browserify command:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Browserify parses the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for `require()` calls to traverse the entire dependency graph of your project.

Drop a single `<script>` tag into your html and you're done!

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

---

Not only is it fun to write client-side scripts like this but browserify will bundle it all together into a nice and tidy minified single script file :D

Comment: I've heard of browserify -- is there an example without browserify -- and doing namespacing -- like `Company.Views.ViewObject` in the browser but just `ViewObject` in node.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the code some more I think you're code should work fine. What you want is to namespace all your code so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace right? So what you need is a single object in the global namespace that you then put all your code under.

> Note: The global namespace in the browser is `window` in case you didn't know.

For example, JQuery creates only two global objects: `jQuery` and `$`. Everything you do with JQuery involves only those two global objects. JQuery even has a compatibility mode that disables the dollar sign so then you only have the `jQuery` object. The pattern people use to get the dollar sign back even when it's been disabled is to do this:

```
(function ($) {
    // Do stuff with $
})(jQuery);
```

It's a self-invoking function that passes the `jQuery` object into itself which then becomes the `$` argument. That way you can still have the convenience of the dollar sign without clogging up the global `window` object with yet another property. In your code (`this.helloWorld`) the `this` keyword refers to the global namespace (unless your code is wrapped inside another function or something and you didn't post it). What you've done is create a property on the `window` object (global namespace) called `helloWorld`, you set it to an empty object, and you pass it in. But you only do this if `exports` is `undefined`. That's the part that identifies if you're in node or not. `exports` will only be `undefined` if you're in the browser because `exports` is only available in node modules (just don't add an `exports` property to the global namespace in the browser, lol).

> Note: Node has no application-wide "global" namespace that things get put into by default. Everything in node is scoped to the module level. So even if you define a variable on the first line of your module you can still define the exact same variable on the first line of another module and they won't conflict with each other. There is however, a `global` object in node that truly is global and you can access its properties from any module. I do not encourage you to use the `global` object, like, ever. If you need to use that object then you should probably reconsider your application structure.

Whatever you attach to `exports` in node becomes available to any other module that requires it.

```
// helloWorld.js
exports.message = "Hello, world!";
```

and then...

```
// main.js
var helloWorld = require('./helloWorld.js');

// Now all the properties are available on the variable `helloWorld`.

console.log(helloWorld.message);

// Prints "Hello, world!" to the console.
```

In the browser you want to do something similar by attaching a single uniquely named object to `window` and then whomever uses your script should access all your functions through that "namespace". So finally we have this:

```
// helloWorld.js

(function (myNamespace) {
    myNamespace.message = "Hello, world!";
})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this.helloWorld = {} : exports)
```

If `exports` does not exist then add `helloWorld` to `this` (which refers to `window` when in the global scope like it is in this example) and pass that in. If `exports` *does* exist then pass it in instead. Now inside the function we can attach properties and methods to `myNamespace` and they'll either be attached to `window.helloWorld` or `exports` depending on the environment.

I could add the above `helloWorld.js` file to my node application and use it like this:

```
// nodeScript.js
var helloWorld = require('./helloWorld.js');
console.log(helloWorld.message);
```

Or I could add the above `helloWorld.js` file to my web app. Your page might look like this:

```
// index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script src="helloWorld.js" />
        <script src="clientScript.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="messageBox"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your script might look like this:

```
// clientScript.js
document.getElementById('messageBox').innerHTML = helloWorld.message;
```

The above page would end up with "Hello, world!" inside the `div` because it read the message from our module's exposed properties :)

Hopefully that clears things up. Sorry for jumping in with browserify at first instead of directly answering your original question. I do highly recommend browserify though :)